# How to add sidebar to Isola theme?

Tags: theme-development, sidebar

I am using Automattic's own Isola theme on my blog. It's a single column theme and it has a sidebar which pops up from the left if clicked on show more kind of button on the left side of site title.

Somehow I managed to disable the sidebar by removing the linking javascript event and the attached HTML. Now I want to add a sidebar to the right for related posts, ads and other stuffs.

How can I do so? Is there any specific detailed tutorial on the internet for this? I have heard the sidebars have to be registered somewhere, but I totally didn't get the stuffs. I am looking for detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the **functions.php** file inside of your theme and search for `register_sidebar` it could look like this:

```
function isola_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'Sidebar', 'isola' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => '',
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ));
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'isola_widgets_init' );
```

and change it to e.g.:

```
function isola_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'Sidebar', 'isola' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => '',
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'Sidebar 2', 'isola' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-2',
        'description'   => '',
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'isola_widgets_init' );
```

Comment: Explain me more! What does it does? Will it appear at the side as I am wanting? Or the same way it was by default in Isola theme?

Comment: For me, they just aren't appearing. :/

Comment: To show widgets in the sidebar location of your choice in the frontend, head into header.php or footer.php etc. inside of your tempalte folder and put there this code `<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ); ?>` . Of course, put some widget in the newly created "Sidebar 2" box in the widget section of WP admin, so something will show in header or footer etc. section of your page.